# What can you do to a file without triggering the "Change" Timestamp?

Tags: linux, bsd, stat, timestamps

What can you do to a file without triggering the "Change" stat?  For instance, it appears that simply changing a bit will trigger Change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the file. That will update its access time (unless disabled with a mount option like `noatime`), but not its inode change time.

Anything else, whether it's changing the file's data, changing its metadata, or renaming it, updates the change time. That's by design.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably by "change stat" you mean the `ctime` of the file? In which case the simple answer is, not very much...

The `ctime` records when the file's inode (essentially it's metadata) was last changed so any change to, for example, the permissions of the file will cause the `ctime` to change.

On top of that changing the contents of the file will change it's size and/or update it's `mtime`, both of which will be recorded in the inode which will cause the `ctime` to change.

About the only change to an inode which doesn't cause `ctime` to change is the updating of `atime` when you read a file.