# When was file created

Tags: files, time

How can i see when a file was created. I have looked at man page

`ls -lc` is for last modification of file status

`ls -lu` for  access time

`ls -l`  not exactly indicated which time, last changed?

I tried these, but they don't give me time the file was created.

Comment: *nix systems don't keep track of file creation time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian explains your problem

Comment: [What are the legitimate uses of the `touch` command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/what-are-the-legitimate-uses-of-the-touch-command/109005#109005) The lack of create time is covered in that Q&A.

Comment: Also this Q&A: [get age of given file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/get-age-of-given-file/102692#102692)

Comment: In OS X you can use `ls -lU`, `stat -f%B`, `GetFileInfo -d`, or `mdls -n kMDItemFSCreationDate`.

Answer (score 8):

On OS/X or FreeBSD, it's the -U option. Linux now also stores the birth/creation time on most of its native file systems, but there's no API to retrieve it yet (**2018 edit**: since kernel 4.11, there is now a [`statx()` system call](/a/452058), and since glibc 2.28 a libc wrapper for it and since coreutils 8.31, GNU `stat` can display it, and (**2021 edit**) since 8.32 GNU `ls` can display it with `--time=birth`).

On ext4 filesystems, you can use debugfs to get it though:

```
$ sudo debugfs /dev/some/fs
stat /some/file
[...]
crtime: 0x53208d7a:9045625c -- Wed Mar 12 16:38:18 2014
[...]
```

(where `/some/file` is the path within that filesystem)

For NTFS filesystems, and assuming you're using ntfs-3g to mount it, see [How do I get the creation date of a file on an NTFS logical volume?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87275/22565)

If you have a recent enough Linux system, you can use `xfs_io`'s `statx` subcommand to invoke the new `statx()` system call and get the birth time:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 xfs_io -c 'statx -v' /some/file
[...]
stat.btime = Thu Feb  7 17:11:20 2019
[...]
```

(here using UTC time with `TZ=UTC0` as otherwise the date would be ambiguous as the UTC offset is not output). Or with `statx -r` which gives you the nanosecond part and a more easily parseable time:

```
$ xfs_io -c 'statx -r' /some/file
[...]
stat.btime.tv_sec = 1549559480
stat.btime.tv_nsec = 964691587
[...]
```

See also [this other Q&A](/a/452058) for a way to invoke `statx()` when your kernel is new enough to support it but when your libc is not.

With GNU `stat` 8.31 or newer on systems with glibc 2.28 or newer and a kernel 4.11 or newer:

```
$ stat /some/file | grep Birth:
 Birth: 2018-05-24 16:27:28.415875403 +0100
$ stat -c '%.9W %w' /some/file
1527175648.415875403 2018-05-24 16:27:28.415875403 +0100
```

With GNU `ls` 8.32 or newer on systems with glibc 2.28 or newer and a kernel 4.11 or newer:

```
$ ls -l --time=birth --full-time /some/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 2333836 2018-05-24 16:27:28.415875403 +0100 /some/file
```

Traditionally, Unix didn't store a creation time.

Note that that value maybe has less meaning than you might think.

The *modification time* reflects the age of the data in that file, the *access time* when it was last accessed, the *inode change-time* is very useful to backup software for instance, because you know nothing about that file has changed since that time (except possibly its full path for which you can have a look at the ctime of its directory components).

The *creation time* is when the inode spawn into existence (well had a link count going from 0 to 1, that inode might have been allocated and removed in a previous life), it doesn't reflect the age of any data associated with that file (data is written after the file has been created), it doesn't tell us whether a file *by that path* went into existence at that time (the file we're looking at can have been created with a different path and linked or moved there later).

Comment: Note with `debugfs` the paths used here must be either relative or absolute (leading `/` is not needed) to the root of the filesystem and not the system root.

Comment: @Graeme, `debugfs` has a `cd` command, so relative paths are relative to that debugfs working directory managed by that `cd` command, but yes the absolute paths are paths in that file system, so relative to the root of the filesystem, I've updated the answer.

Comment: From your last part, an example of where the creation time is effectively invalidated is when programs update files by writing the data to a different file and atomically moving the location of the new file to the original. The inode and creation time for the new file is used rather than the original, as might be expected. Two programs that do this by default are `rsync` and `vim`.