# Finding a file which created X minutes back (without GNU/BSD find)

Tags: find, timestamps

I am using the `find` command to find the files which were created with in 30 minutes.

```
find . -ctime -30m
```

But it is giving files from up to 30 days. I have tried `-mmin` too but it is showing that `-mmin` is not a valid option.

What is wrong in my `find` command?

Output for `uname -rs` is `AIX 2`.

Comment: `-ctime` is for last inode change time, not creation time. `-mmin/-cmin` are GNU extensions (though also supported by some BSDs).

Comment: What's your system? (output of `uname -rs`)?

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas output for `uname -rs` is `AIX 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [@JRFerguson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146593/22565).

To obtain a reference file whose modification time is 30 minutes in the past, you can do portably (precision of one second):

```
TZ=ZZZ0 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ0:30 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" /some/ref/file
```

And then do:

```
find . -newer /some/ref/file
```

That only works for intervals of 50 hours:

```
TZ=ZZZ-24:59:59 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ24:59:59 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" file
```

being the oldest file you can obtain portably (POSIXly) with that method.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas Could you please explain `TZ=ZZZ0` in the above By using that I got my solution but I don't understand about `TZ=ZZZ0`. As that is not in the format of `[[cc]yy]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`

Comment: @Aravind, `TZ=ZZZ0 touch` defines the current timezone as being called `ZZZ` (the name doesn't matter so picking a random meaningless one to avoid confusion) and being 0 hours off from UTC for the `touch` command.

Answer (score 2):

AIX's `find` lacks the nice GNU features.

You can work around this easily.  Create two "reference" files with timestamps that mark the boundaries of interest:

```
touch -amt 201407251200 myref1
touch -amt 201407251230 myref2
```

Now do:

```
find . -type f \( -newer myref1 -a ! -newer myref2 \) -exec ls -ld {} +
```

This references a file's `mtime` or modification time.  This will be a file's creation timestamp if no further modifications (writes) were made to it, otherwise it will represent the last time a change was made to the *data*.  For directories, the `mtime` is updated when new objects are added or old ones deleted.  Classic Unix/Linux lacks a true creation timestamp, although this is implemented (and available for retrieval) on certain platforms.  (see further [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/when-was-file-created?rq=1).  MAC OS users can use 'ls -lU' to obtain it.

Don't confuse `ctime` with "creation". The `ctime` of the stat() structure represents the last timestamp for inode changes (i.e. permissions, ownership and the name of the object).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-cmin`. From `man` page of `find`,

```
   -cmin n
          File’s status was last changed n minutes ago.

   -ctime n
          File’s status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the  interpreta-
          tion of file status change times.
```

Comment: @ Ramesh I have tried `-cmin` also. But it is showing `-cmin` is not a valid option

Comment: Which version of `find` you are using?

Comment: @ Ramesh I am not sure about my `find` command but I am using `ksh88`

Comment: Try -mmin then.  It should coincide with file creation time if you didn't modify the file since then.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal I don't think that there's any version of find that supports `-mmin` but not `-cmin`. The standard options are `-Xtime` which count in days only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` instead:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find ();
use File::stat;

use vars qw(*name);
*name   = *File::Find::name;
my $now = time;

File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '.');

sub wanted {
    print "$name\n" if stat($_)->mtime > ($now - 30*60)
                    and $name ne ".";
}
```

Except `OSX` or `FreeBSD` (use `ls -U`), you can not get creation date of a file.

If you are on `ext2/3/4` filesystems, you can use [debugfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html) to get creation date of file.