# How to check when a symlink was created?

Tags: symlink

There is a symlink `linked_dir` in `dir`, and I am trying to find when it was created. Within `dir`, I ran

```
stat -c %w useq_242_nyc
```

But the only output is

```
-
```

How can I check when this symlink was created?

Comment: Not all filesystems keep the creation time, or are configured to keep it. It looks like this inode doesn't have the creation time, but in the case of a symbolic link, I'd say it is highly likely that it was never modified after creation, so your best bet is `stat -c %y`.

Comment: I just found this page, which might offer a solution (I have not read it through very thoroughly, your mileage may vary): https://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/.

Comment: @berndbausch oh the `%y` option worked :) or at least it gave a datetime, which presumably is the creation time

Comment: @anonuser01, it's likely as it's not really possible to *modifiy* a symlink, though one can use `touch -hd 1999-02-01 symlink` for instance on some systems to change the modification time arbitrarily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When was file created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119698)

Comment: Well, `%y` shows you the time of last modification.  In most symlink cases it is identical to the creation time, but see Stephane Chazelas' caveat.